# Django add into many-to-many field for each item in a queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Suppose I have the following model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    blogs = model.ManyToManyField(Blog)
```

What is the best way to add a blog to the field for multiple users e.g. I want to add an instance of Blog called blog to all users (i.e. `User.object.all()`). Do I have to iterate over each result individually or is there a way to do it all at once?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do a `bulk_create` on the through table. For example:

```
blog = Blog.objects.get(…)
users = User.object.all()

User.blogs.through.objects.bulk_create(
    [User.blogs.through(user_id=user.pk, blog_id=blog.pk) for user in users]
)
```

That will do one database query.